# magento category save not working

Tags: magento2

In magento 2 backend when edit and save category page it giving below message 
"The value of attribute "name" must be set" or sometime giving 500 error. Please refer screen-shots below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z74BT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WonDU.png

This issue only with some of categories not all.

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the var/log/exception.log file and in the logs of your web server for additional info.

Comment: I have the same problem , do you get solution for it please ?